# GET Variables are confused when HTACCESS is involved

Tags: php, .htaccess

Whenever I add an extra `$_GET[]` variable into the url and then rewrite it with HTACCESS, PHP seems to get confused and assigns 1 variable (in this case $r) to entire rest of the url string

For example:
mydomain.com/index/r/policy/cookiepolicy

if I `echo $r` in index.php I get `policy/cookiepolicy`, it should only be `policy`. Instead of loading the policy.php page, it reverts to the default case (because it contains two `GET` variables and cannot find the correct match) and brings me back to the home page. However if I use the "ugly" URL like this: `mydomain.com/index.php?r=policy&tab=cookiepolicy`, everything seems to work fine

**htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^index/r/(.*)$ /index.php?r=$1 
RewriteRule ^index/r/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?r=$1&tab=$2
```

**policy.php**

```
$k = $_GET["tab"];
//I'm loading the tabs using if() statements
if($k == "cookiepolicy"){
...
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
                $r = $_GET["r"];


                if (isset($r) && !empty($r)) {
                    switch ($r) {
                        //...(more cases here)
                        //Why do the tabs not load for the policy page?
                        case "policy";
                            include("pages/policy.php");
                            break;
                        //...(more cases here)
                        default:
                            include("pages/home.php");
                            break;
                    }
                } else {
                    include("pages/home.php");
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried telling the rewrite engine to stop after the first match? `RewriteRule ^index/r/(.*)$ /index.php?r=$1 [L]` (the [L] flag) ... or you can reverse the order of the rules.

Comment: @CD001 Yup, I've tried this. This problem just suddenly started, before it was working fine./

Comment: Might be because `(.*)` is matching the `/`; so in the first instance `$_GET['r'] = '/policy/cookiepolicy'` - try `([^/]*)` instead?

Comment: wait... thank you! it just started working again! apparently I just needed to reverse the rules. (might as well post an answer so you get some credit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, with your rewrite rules, the first one in the list is:

```
RewriteRule ^index/r/(.*)$ /index.php?r=$1
```

Because that matches the `/` character `$_GET['r']` is being assigned the value `policy/cookiepolicy`.

You can either exclude the `/` from the match by using `([^/]*)` instead of `(.*)` or simply reverse the order of the rules so that the second match is evaluated before the first:

```
RewriteRule ^index/r/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?r=$1&tab=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^index/r/(.*)$ /index.php?r=$1 [L]
```

That way `/policy/cookiepolicy` is caught by the first match and:

```
$_GET['r'] = 'policy'
$_GET['tab'] = 'cookiepolicy'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index/r/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?r=$1&tab=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^index/r/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```